# how to algorithm this?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, uitableview

I have a number of fruit baskets, all of them have a random amount of apples and they have different properties.

```
arrayOfBaskets = [
    ["basketId": 1, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 1, "fromCountry":1, "numberOfApples": 5],
    ["basketId": 2, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 1, "fromCountry":1, "numberOfApples": 6],
    ["basketId": 3, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 2, "fromCountry":1, "numberOfApples": 3],
    ["basketId": 4, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 2, "fromCountry":1, "numberOfApples": 7],
    ["basketId": 5, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 1, "fromCountry":2, "numberOfApples": 8],
    ["basketId": 6, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 1, "fromCountry":2, "numberOfApples": 4],
    ["basketId": 7, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 2, "fromCountry":2, "numberOfApples": 9],
    ["basketId": 8, "typeOfPesticidesUsed": 2, "fromCountry":2, "numberOfApples": 5]
]
```

in this case, how do I formulate an algorithm of sorts to output into an array like so:

```
uniquePairingOfBasketProperties = [
    ["typeOfPesticidesUsed": 1, "fromCountry":1],
    ["typeOfPesticidesUsed": 2, "fromCountry":1],
    ["typeOfPesticidesUsed": 1, "fromCountry":2],
    ["typeOfPesticidesUsed": 2, "fromCountry":2]
]
```

my main point is so that I can get my UITableView to know how many rows it should have. Which in this case is 4 instead of total number of baskets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? You have an array of dictionaries. You want to divide those dictionaries into "buckets" where each bucket has a unique combination of pesticide type and country of origin?

Assuming that's the case, how about this:

```
let kNumberOfCountries = 2
uniqueValue = basket["typeOfPesticidesUsed"] * kNumberOfCountries +
  basket["fromCountry"]
```

`uniqueValue` will jump in large steps based on the type of pesticide, and then change by 1s based on the country of origin. (think of a rectangular grid where the country number starts at 1 on the left and increases to the right, and the pesticide number starts at 1 at the top and increases as you go down. The unique value number is 1 at the top left square, counts up to the right, then wraps around to the next row and keeps counting up by 1s.

You can then group your table view based on `uniqueVaue`.

If you want to know how many unique parings you have, create an empty set of integers. Loop through your array of baskets. Calculate the uniqueValue for that basket, and add it to the set of uniqueValues (sets only have one entry for each value.) Once you are done looping, the number of entries in the set is the number of unique pairings you have. If you use an `NSCountedSet`, you can even get the count of the number of baskets with each pairing. (I don't know if Swift has a native counted set collection. It didn't last time I checked.)

### EDIT:

It looks like Swift does NOT have a native counted set collection (at least not yet.) There is, however, at least one [**open source Swift counted set**](https://github.com/JadenGeller/Handbag/) (aka a bag) on Github

Comment: Why i'm not clear as to how to do it is that occasionally a pairing might not be available. if I added fromCountry 3 into the mix but it only uses pesticide 1, and not two, then multiplying by the total number countries doesn't help..

Comment: Yes it does help. My system lays out a grid of possible values. If some pairings aren't found, those entries in the grid will be empty. That's OK. If you go through, adding each uniqueValue to a set, at the end of the loop the number of entries in the set will be the number of unique pairings, whether all of the combinations occur or not.

Comment: ok I just tried it out on paper and it makes sense. Let me try that first! Thanks!